# using ORDER BY in a prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I'm creating a web app that displays a table using data from a database using Java MVC.

I have a prepared statement that I'm using to generate the table that works fine until i try and use ORDER BY.

I'm quite confused as when I run this query in the mySQL workbench it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments ORDER BY date
```

However when i put it into my prepared statement in the browser it returns an unordered list.

```
public void doRead(){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM appointments ORDER BY date";

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(query);
        this.results = ps.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help.

as requested im printing the table with this method here:

```
try {
        while(this.results.next()){
            Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
            appointment.setAppointmentID(this.results.getInt("appointment_id"));
            appointment.setDescription(this.results.getString("description"));
            appointment.setDate(this.results.getString("date"));

            table += "<tr>";
            table += "<td>";
            table += appointment.getDescription();
            table += "</td>"; 
            table += "<td>";
            table += appointment.getDate();
            table += "</td>";
            table += "</tr>";
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    table += "</table>";
    return table;
}
```

the output in browser:

Dentist 2015-09-17

Dentist 2015-09-17

Dentist 2015-09-17

Dentist 2015-10-09

Dentist 2015-09-03

Dentist 2015-09-03

Dentist 2015-09-03

Comment: Show us how you are printing them

Comment: Can you not sort it after, from java?

Comment: Are you storing the results to something that does not retain order, such as, a HashSet?

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? Is the order wrong or an exception?

Comment: edited answer @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: the result is stored in ResultSet @PaulZepernick

Comment: the order is wrong @Jered

Comment: The type of your `date` column is VARCHAR? Can you provide an example of the `table` String (your output)?
I'm interested in your `date` format.
Could it be that your Appointments are sorted like (date):
09:15:00 02-02-2015
12:00:00 01-01-205
13:00:00 03-03-2015

Comment: currently the type of my date column is DATETIME, it was DATE but i changed it to DATETIME hoping that would solve the issue, but it did not, output edited in the answer. @AlexeyGromov

Comment: Let's try to clean up your code, to reduce possible side-effects. Do all DB/related work in one method - use local variables. 1. create `Connection con` 2. create `PreparedStatement ps` from this connection 3. `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()` 4. process `rs` creating an `output` String (in the same method or pass it as parameter to another private method, do NOT hold it in an Object field) 5. `rs.close()` 6. `ps.close()` 7. `conn.close()` 8. `return output`

Comment: I am a little perplexed.  You say you are using web MVC.  What is the purpose of the Appointment object if the table is really being created in the java code?  Are you sure that you are not building up those appointment objects into some sort of collection that is being processed by your view?  I have a feeling that something else is changing your order after your db query comes back.  Also, trying putting a debug log or system.out in the loop to see if that is printing the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

DATE is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Use backticks:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM appointments ORDER BY `date`";
```

Also better make `results` a local variable and close it.

Tip:

Use a StringBuilder instead of String for `table`. Much faster, less memory hungry. Better even would be to pass a PrintWriter for outputting.

Comment: hi, thanks for this answer but unfortinately thats had no effect on the outcome @JoopEggen, i attempted to order by bescription too and still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a sort order "ASC":

```
SELECT * FROM appointments ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: *"ASC"* is the default behavior if you don't add a ordering direction. So it is not necessary.